# Priority field in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring-mvc

I need to create a priority field in my HTML form. Currently i am using radio buttons but it does not suffice my needs. The radio button should change background color onclick depending on the level of priority. Also i am not able to read the values to the controller.

[image: Priority]

The priority field should change colors according to the matrix above. In the form only the first row is present for the priority field. 
This is the HTML i am using for priority

```
`       <input type="radio" id="1" class="priority">
        <input type="radio" id="2" class="priority">
        <input type="radio" id="3" class="priority">
        <input type="radio" id="4" class="priority">
        <input type="radio" id="5" class="priority">`
```

I am using spring MVC framework.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PsmwN/8/)

add `value` attribute to the radio buttons like

```
<input type="radio" name="1" id="r1" value="a rating">
```

then some script to read the radio button values like:

```
var htmlStr = $(this).attr("value");
$(".indicator").html(htmlStr);
```

I've tried some workaround for the sake of "changing color" in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsmwN/8/)

Added this html, to act as the radio buttons that changes color:

```
<div class="circ"></div>
<div class="circ"></div>
<div class="circ"></div>
<div class="circ"></div>
<div class="circ"></div>
```

with this css, to take it under the radio buttons:

```
.circ{
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Then add `z-index: 9` to the radio button css rule to make it stay on top of the `.circ` divs and be clickable. Finally, add `opacity: 0` to make it invisible, so the `.circ` divs under will appear on screen. Now you can change the color of the `.circ` divs accordingly using some script.

PS: You can't just edit radio button's background color, instead use background images

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i understud your question correct, but if so this [demo code (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/PsmwN/1/) might help. 
(its just a demo, and would still have to be adapted for your needs)

It simply sets the color class on the Click event of every RadioButton.

CSS

```
.color1 {
    background:red;
}
.color2 {
    background:green;
}
.color3 {
    background:yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="priority">
    <input type="radio" name="1" id="1">
    <input type="radio" name="1" id="2">
    <input type="radio" name="1" id="3">
    <input type="radio" name="1" id="4">
    <input type="radio" name="1" id="5">
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $(".priority input").on("click", function () {
        $(".priority").attr("class", "priority color" + this.id);
    });
})
```

**tested with Chrome 34+**

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can use jQuery plugin **Colourful rating system**. It comes with good options so that you can set the color as required.

[DEMO](http://demo.marcofolio.net/colourful_rating_system/)

example as follows:

the HTML

```
<ul id="rating">
   <li><a href="#">This is just a piece of crap</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Nothing too new or interesting</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Not bad, I like it</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">I would like to see more of this</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is the best thing I've seen</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#rating { list-style:none; }
#rating li { display:inline; float:left; }
#rating li a { display:block; width:80px; height:80px; border:1px solid #888; background-color:#333;
   text-indent:-9999px; box-shadow:0 0 5px #888; border-radius:40px; }

#ratinginfo { clear:left; width:350px; }
#ratinginfo p { text-align:center; padding:10px;
   box-shadow:0 0 5px #888; border-radius:40px; }
```

After we're done loading jQuery and the Color plugin, we're ready to use jQuery to now animate the circles to the right colour and display the text.

```
// Variable to set the duration of the animation
var animationTime = 500;

// Variable to store the colours
var colours = ["bd2c33", "e49420", "ecdb00", "3bad54", "1b7db9"];

// Add rating information box after rating
var ratingInfobox = $("<div />")
   .attr("id", "ratinginfo")
   .insertAfter($("#rating"));

// Function to colorize the right ratings
var colourizeRatings = function(nrOfRatings) {
   $("#rating li a").each(function() {
      if($(this).parent().index() <= nrOfRatings) {
         $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor : "#" + colours[nrOfRatings] } , animationTime);
      }
   });
};

// Handle the hover events
$("#rating li a").hover(function() {

   // Empty the rating info box and fade in
   ratingInfobox
      .empty()
      .stop()
      .animate({ opacity : 1 }, animationTime);

   // Add the text to the rating info box
   $("<p />")
      .html($(this).html())
      .appendTo(ratingInfobox);

   // Call the colourize function with the given index
   colourizeRatings($(this).parent().index());
}, function() {

   // Fade out the rating information box
   ratingInfobox
      .stop()
      .animate({ opacity : 0 }, animationTime);

   // Restore all the rating to their original colours
   $("#rating li a").stop().animate({ backgroundColor : "#333" } , animationTime);
});

// Prevent the click event and show the rating
$("#rating li a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("You voted on item number " + ($(this).parent().index() + 1));
});
```

for complete documentation and source code click [HERE](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/jquery_quickie_colourful_rating_system_with_css3.html)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).