# how to apply different colors for first select and second select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to apply different colors for first checkbox and second checkbox, 1st checkbox should be green and 2nd checkbox should be red. if user unchecked the green and the next should be green color. if user unchecked red means the next check should be red.
help me please.

```
<script class="jsbin" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
<body>
<form name="disc">
  <p>Select Only Two</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ad"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ai"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="as"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ac"/>
</form>
<script>
  $("form").on("click", ":checkbox", function(event){
  $(":checkbox:not(:checked)", this.form).prop("disabled", function(){
    return $(this.form).find(":checkbox:checked").length == 2;
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Toggle the className

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192957/priority-field-in-html-form/23193967#23193967 - check this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdpu4L26/)

JS:

```
$(function() {

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        span.addClass('checked');
    }
    $(this).wrap(span).hide();
});

function doCheck() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        if($('#disc').find(":checkbox:checked").length >= 1) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).removeClass('red');
            $(this).removeClass('green');
            $(this).addClass('default');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
        }
    } else {
        console.log($('#disc').find(":checkbox:checked").length);
        if($('#disc').find(":checkbox:checked").length < 2) {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).removeClass('default');
            if($('#disc').find(":checkbox:checked").length < 1) {
                $(this).addClass('green');
            } else {

                    $(this).addClass('red');

            }
            $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
        }
    }
}

function doDown() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
}

function doUp() {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox, .radio {
width: 19px;
height: 20px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/raz13m.jpg");
display: block;
clear: left;
float: left;
}

.checked {
 background-position: 0px -50px;   
}

.clicked {
 background-position: 0px -25px;
}

.clicked.checked {
 background-position: 0px -75px;
}


.green {
background-color: green;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.default {
background-color: none;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

PS: This is a slight modification I made to the accepted fiddle from [CSS Styling Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes), so credit for the background coloring goes to the original author [Jeff B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179216/jeff-b)

Comment: Thanks buddy, but after uncheck green checkbox the next check should be green but here it see red

Comment: Try modifying it to fit your specific need. Look in to the else condition inside doCheck().

Comment: i tried like below but is not working:
       else if($('#disc').find(":checkbox:checked").length == 1){

                    $(this).addClass('red');
          
            }  else {
          $(this).addClass('green');
      }
                $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
            }
        }

Comment: Do you want to automatically change red to green when there is only one box checked?

Comment: no sir, not like that. 1st checkbox should be green and 2nd checkbox should be red. if user unchecked the green and the next selected one should be green color. if user unchecked red means the next check should be red.

Comment: in CSS background we used http://i48.tinypic.com/raz13m.jpg this image bt i want real check boxes. how can i get?

Comment: That's a limitation with real checkbox; all options to apply background color depends on custom checkboxes. May be you can create your own sprite with checkboxes which look closer to the real thing.

Comment: ok sir.. thanq. now i have to know the color of check box and i have to assign value for each color. can you help me?

Comment: Didn't get you. You want to assign a particular value to the checkbox based on which color background is set?

Comment: i want to assign green=1 and red=0

Comment: i think 

if($('.green').length > 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('red');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('green');
                }
in this block i have to assign but i dnt knw how to assign

Comment: [This should do for you](http://jsfiddle.net/pdpu4L26/2/). Is this some homework assignment? You seem to make me do all your work. Please accept the answer and up-vote it if it helps.

Comment: it is mini project sir.

Comment: if($('.green').length > 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('red');
          var y = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('green');
          var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
                }
                $(this).children().prop("checked", true);

Comment: i trid above code to store value in varible.. but i want use that variable in php sessions

Comment: I have provided the fiddle in my last comment. I am leaving this discussion. Forced to comment here because you don't have enough rep to use chat. Anyways, if you found my answer useful, please up vote or accept.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60838/discussion-on-answer-by-jayachandran-how-to-apply-different-colors-for-first-sel).

Comment: $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            span.addClass('checked');
        }
        $(this).wrap(span).hide();
    });

Comment: can you xplain why we used span here? becoz of span i am nt getting class id

Comment: hello sir, i am poor in javascript, jquery and ajax. Can you teach me?

setti565@gmail.com. you can contact me through mail. plz leave your comment

Comment: hello sie, final question please try to help me...

as you told i copied the code and convert it to my requirements..thanks for all.

but now i have to check at least two checked in those four and i am running total  11 questions. i tried some codes but those are not working. 

thanks sir